# Is there any ways to catch an ArithmeticException during division by zero for a double typed data in java

Tags: java, oop, try-catch

```
double div(double a,double b)
{
    double c;
    try
    {
    c=a/b;
    System.out.println("Result="+c);
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e)
    {
    System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero");
    }
    return c;
}
```

If I pass A = 10 (non zero ) and B = 0 . The block doesn't catch any ArithmeticException , instead it just returns "infinity" . But if I change the type of these variables into int , then the catch block gets executed , but the issue with this method is that if I pass A = 2 and B = 5 , it will return zero as they are of integer type . Is there any way in which when I pass  A = 2 and B = 5 , it returns 0.4 and if B = 0 , it should catch the ArithmeticException .

Comment: As you correctly observed, there is no exception. But you can always check for infinity.

Comment: Note that your example does throw an exception if `b==0`. I assume you meant to use floats?

Comment: @shmosel , oops my bad , I pasted the other version of the code

Comment: @Hulk they're not always equivalent: https://ideone.com/gcs340

Comment: Does that code even compile? It has at least 2 issues: 1) 2 return types defined, 2) `c` may not be initialized, i.e. if the exception was thrown.

Comment: @shmosel yes, I know, and there are other ways in which a floating point division could yield INF. One of them being that an input is already INF.

Comment: @Thomas , Again my bad mate , i messed up when i pasted the code , and its just a method , the variables are being initialized in the main method itself

Comment: "the variables are being initialized in the main method itself" - your code declares `c` locally though. In general, when posting code here, try to produce a [mcve] - note that this should mean the code does compile and reflects the issue. We can't help if the code is full of errors.

Comment: @Thomas , I am new over here , I will take your advice and will implement in my future questions  . Regarding this question , a and b are initialised in the main method and are passed into the method by creating an instance of the class

Comment: No, you don't get the point about initialization: `a` and `b` _might_ be initialized in the main method but if they are passed to the call of `div(a, b)` then note that in that method there's a local declaration of the parameters `a` and `b`. But those are not the problem: `c` is - it isn't guaranteed to be initialized when you're trying to return it (i.e. an exception _might_ be thrown and thus the assignment `c = ...` never happens).

Comment: @Thomas , can you share ur twitter handle

Comment: I don't have any but why would you need it?

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, floating point division works differently from integer division, and it doesn't disallow div by zero. Instead, some inputs lead to `+INF`, `-INF` or `NaN`, (see [JLS 15.17.2. Division Operator /](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)).

You can check the inputs and/or the output. One way to check if the output is within the range of finite `double` values is the method [`Double.isFinite`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#isFinite(double))

Also note that a non-void method can only terminate in two ways - by returning a value of by throwing an Exception. So you cannot just print/log in your catch block - you must either choose a value to return, or throw.

If your inputs are `int`, and you just want a `double` result, you could just do something like the following, because the range of possible results fits nicely into `double`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Result=" + div(2, 5));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

static double div(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot divide by zero");
    }

    return (double) a / (double) b;
}
```